# Erro ao ler arquivo para teste de Skott-Knott no R

Tags: r

Sou iniciante no R e não estou conseguindo realizar o teste de Skott-Knott pela biblioteca ExpDes.pt.

```
    # expdes.pt
    library("ExpDes.pt")
    options(digits = 4)
    # with transformed data 
    dic(db$Insetiscida, db$Lagartas.log, sigF = 0.05, mcomp = 'sk', sigT = 0.05)
    
    # < media = mais eficacia no controle da praga.
```

Ao executar o programa acima, recebo o erro:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : line 3 did not have 3 elements

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EAwfLVq-XhuTeYqaE39JLbnWDBQSU-5x/view?usp=sharing) dos dados.

Comment: Matheus, boa tarde! Disponibilize o dataset. O erro mencionado diz que a linha 3 não contem 3 elementos. Abraço!

Comment: Segue o [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EAwfLVq-XhuTeYqaE39JLbnWDBQSU-5x/view?usp=sharing) e obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Pelo que vi não existe uma variável chamada `Lagartas.log` e sim com o nome de `Lagartas.C`. Tente mudar esse nome na linha `dic(db$Insetiscida, db$Lagartas.C, sigF = 0.05, mcomp = 'sk', sigT = 0.05)`. Claro que se esse for todo o seu código. Para a leitura do xlsx eu utilizei o pacote readxl. Abraço!